# redraw-display when focused

Tags: display, linux, gui-emacs

I am using Emacs 25 in SUSE linux and when I switch to a workspace where Emacs is the front window almost none of the text is visible. I have to call `redraw-display` in order to get it refresh the screen so I can see my text. Is there someway that I could make this automatic? Like whenever Emacs gets focused it calls `redraw-display`?

Comment: See section on [input focus](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Input-Focus.html) in the Emacs Lisp manual. You can use the `focus-in-hook`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a hook to the focus event. `(add-hook 'focus-in-hook 'redraw-display)`. Thanks to Håkon Hægland for the Answer!